# Why is my screen acting weird

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, graphics, unibody

[image: Black is turning green - but not everywhere and not on screendump or on my ext. screen (photo taken with iPhone)]

Black is turning green - but not everywhere and not on screendump or on my ext. screen (photo taken with iPhone). If I press the unibody hard on the left side, then I can make the green disappear, but that's not a solution.

This is a MacBook Pro (15”, mid-2010) 2.66GHz Intel Core i7 with 8GB 1067 MHz DDR3, an NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 512 MB / Intel HD Graphics 288 Mb, and the OS is El Capitan v.10.11.6

To determine if the problem is caused by a graphics card or not, I would like to know if there is a way to have only one card/processor active at time?

Comment: It looks like the graphics card problem which affected MBPs of that vintage. Apple had a [repair program](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554) if your particular unit was affected, but it has expired.

Comment: Sh.. I should have known that a year ago before it expired (not your fault).

Answer (score 2):

If <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> does not capture the display as you see it, or, if mirroring the display on your external monitor does not reproduce it then it is not the OS which is making that happen.

Your problem may be in the connection of the graphics and screen hardware itself. If pressing the unibody relieves this, you may need to reseat the graphics card or some other component. Has you laptop been dropped recently?

This Mid-2010 MacBook Pro [teardown article](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+Teardown/2212) or [this disassembly video](https://youtu.be/qiBxhA29eaU) might help you ascertain which components you are pressing on.

Also, you may simply be overheating from a clogged vent port. Have they ever been cleaned (since mid-2010 = 6+ years)? This is [a step by step guide to replace the fan](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+Left+Fan+Replacement/3035) if it needs a new one.

Comment: "Has you laptop been dropped recently?" No - and no overheating cause I cleaned it inside when the problem occurred first time (app. a year ago) but now I cannot live with it any longer ... :-(
I have to buy a Y screwdriver and I'll try opening again and see if I can do miracles or I have to spend a fortune on a new comp....